# PHP treated "0" as empty?

Tags: php

I have encounteed an issue with php treating "0" differently.

I run following script on 2 different machines:

```
$a = "0";
if ($a) {
    echo("helo");
}
```

1) Local Machine    -> PHP 5.2.17
    -> it treated "0" as valid and print the 'helo'

2) Server           -> PHP 5.3.6
    -> it treated "0" as empty/false and won't print the 'helo'

Is this due to the php configuration (if yes, what configuration) or php version?

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 (Win32) does *not* print "helo" when `$a = "0";` (just tested it on CLI and through Apache to make sure). You must have had another character in the string as well - maybe a whitespace character that was invisible when printed, like `\r`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how it is supposed to. PHP interprets strings in boolean context. The `"0"` there is equivalent to an actual `0`. (See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

What you meant to test for is probably:

```
if (strlen($a)) {
```

Comment: But it didn't do it in  PHP 5.2.17 ?

Answer (score 2):

`if($a)` should be `FALSE`, as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). It should also be like that on your local machine. Are you sure that on the local machine, you don't have a space after the 0 or something? ("`0<space>`" would be `TRUE`.)

Answer (score 0):

Sound weird to me, I thought "0" was false, you can review [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

Answer (score 0):

PHP may interporate "0" as false as it would be equivilent to null/false/0.

However, it also may interporate it as a string of "0". Thus the if statement would return true, however, I think that would be a bug unless you type cast it to (string).

Like Mario said, check for the strlen($a) or check if( !empty($a) ) that way you will get your definitive answer.

I hope this helps!